# Get Wix Forms data from an external platform

Tags: swift, velo

So I'm new to the Wix platform, and am working in a situation where users fill out a form on my website and the data is stored in a Submission Table. I have been reading through the API references but can't tell if what I am trying to do is possible. Basically, I want to be able to query the table data (through an API I'm guessing) from another platform, like an iOS app built in Xcode and Swift. All the Wix API documentation tutorials seem to point to another Wix site/app getting this API data and no external methods. Is this possible? I want this data to be able to run a function on the app based on the results of the table and I have yet to find documentation for this type of external API call.

Comment: You need to find somewhere to put common storage, something that both the app and wix can access

Comment: @loremipsum Are you saying like instead of storing the form data on Wix, post it to an external storage/database that could be read by the app easier?